# Using Two Monitors in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have two monitors and only one HDMI port. Finally saved up for a second monitor, and after 3 different products, I found this docking station that claims to be compatible with linux but its not working.

I was wondering if someone can help because the mouse and keyboard work just fine, but the monitors don't register.

Docking Station:

---

USB-C Dual HDMI 4K Docking Station with 100W PD Pass-Thru.

---

from:

https://us.targus.com/products/usb-c-dual-hdmi-4k-docking-station-with-100w-pd-pass-thru-dock423tt

I downloaded a few 'drivers' zip files from the support page.

https://www.targus.com/form/download.aspx?regionid=7&sku=DOCK423&tab=driver

and just got a make file and some headers. I'm new to linux and don't know how or which drivers to install. also the support center is closed the for the holidays and I need help.

`xrandr` doesn't notice either.

ran `dmesg` and I think this is relevant but not sure.

```
[    1.065867] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found

[    1.066004] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected

[    1.154597] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)

[    1.154678] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)

[    1.161318] nvme nvme0: pci function 10000:e1:00.0

[    1.161417] pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: can't derive routing for PCI INT A

[    1.161420] nvme 10000:e1:00.0: PCI INT A: no GSI

[    1.165726] nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.

[    1.190791] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhc
```

I think this is my GPU

```
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         logical name: /dev/fb0
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
         configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
         resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:159 memory:6002000000-6002ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
    *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
         description: System peripheral
         product: GNA Scoring Accelerator module
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 8
         bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:600340f000-600340ffff
```

cpu:

```
Acer Aspire 5 'A514-54-501' Core i5-1135G7 2.4GHz
Intel Iris Xe
```

Comment: Maybe the question should be how do I install those drivers, so that my automatically system knows what I'm trying to do?

I was also wondering if anyone can point me to a relatively inexpensive docking station that just works with ubuntu 22.04 out of the box?